# Syncing Contacts to iOS on Mac OS X 10.6

Tags: macos, icloud, data-synchronization, ios

What is the oldest Mac OS version that can do iCloud sync from Contacts/Address Book to a current iOS 9 device (iPhone SE, in this case)? The goal is to sync contacts between my Macbook running OS X 10.6 and my iPhone.

If iCloud sync is not possible, what synchronization options in 10.6 would allow for contact synchronization to current iOS?

Comment: Let me know if my huge guide helps you :D!

Answer (score 1):

According to http://www.apple.com/icloud/setup/mac.html iCloud requires 10.7.5 or later.

Since iCloud encrypts data between the client and the server, you won't find third party options. I would get whatever software you need on 10.6 upgraded and then upgrade the OS or set up virtualization to run 10.6 from within a newer OS if iCloud data sync is needed.

Perhaps you could find a different cloud sync between to that's likely more work and aisle than the above.

Answer (score 1):

As bmike pointed out, [iCloud requires OS X 10.7.5 or later](http://www.apple.com/icloud/setup/mac.html), so syncing Contacts via iCloud is not an option for you.

However, iOS can sync contacts seamlessly through other services, notably Gmail, Yahoo Mail, and Outlook. Since I sync contacts through Gmail, I've provided a guide to help you get started.

### If you have preexisting contacts in iCloud

1. Export your contacts out of iCloud as a vCard. Here's how:

   - Go to [icloud.com](http://icloud.com) in any web browser and sign in to your iCloud account.
   - Click on `Contacts`.
   - Click on any contact in the `All Contacts` section and then hit <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> to select all of your contacts (or <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> if you happen to be using a Windows computer).
   - Click on the gear icon in the lower left-hand corner.
   - Click on `Export vCard`.
   - Choose to save the vCard on your Desktop.
2. Import your contacts into Gmail. Here's how:

   - Go to [mail.google.com](http://mail.google.com) in any web browser and sign in to your primary Gmail account.
   - Click on the `Mail` drop-down menu near the top-left of the Gmail window and choose `Contacts`.
   - Go to the `More` button and select `Import`.
   - Click `Choose file` and find the vCard you saved to your desktop in Step 1.
3. Go to the Settings app on iOS, and go to `Mail, Contacts, Calendars` (on iOS 9 or earlier) or `Contacts` (on iOS 10). If you don't yet have your primary Gmail account setup on your iPhone, follow these instructions:

   - Hit `Add Account` (on iOS 9) or `Accounts` -> `Add Account` (on iOS 10).
   - Choose `Google`, and sign into your primary Gmail account (the one you added your contacts vCard to) on the following screens.
   - Back out all the way to `Mail, Contacts, Calendars` / `Contacts` to continue.
4. Tap on the Gmail account you just added, then toggle `Contacts` on. Back out one step, then toggle `Contacts` off for iCloud. (Choose `Delete from my iPhone` if the prompt appears.)

---

### If you don't have preexisting contacts

1. Go to the Settings app on iOS, and go to `Mail, Contacts, Calendars` (on iOS 9 or earlier) or `Contacts` (on iOS 10). If you don't yet have your primary Gmail account setup on your iPhone, follow these instructions:

   - Hit `Add Account` (on iOS 9) or `Accounts` -> `Add Account` (on iOS 10).
   - Choose `Google`, and sign into your primary Gmail account (the one you added your contacts vCard to) on the following screens.
   - Back out all the way to `Mail, Contacts, Calendars` / `Contacts` to continue.
2. Tap on the Gmail account you just added, then toggle `Contacts` on. Back out one step, then toggle `Contacts` off for iCloud. (Choose `Delete from my iPhone` if the prompt appears.)

---

Now you will be able to access synced contacts on your laptop from [contacts.google.com](http://contacts.google.com) and the Contacts app (by adding the Gmail account to `Internet Accounts` in System Preferences, then turning on `Contacts` for it) and on your iOS or Android device from the Contacts app.

Comment: Looks pretty darn good! Thanks for the comprehensive answer. I'll the question some more time before accepting.

Comment: @user2943160 Yeah, go ahead, no worries.